# UK visa application: “Collection” email rather than refusal?

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, standard-visitor-visas

I received a “collection” email from TLScontact for a UK visa application, but there was not a refusal email.

I checked my spam folder several times because after my passport collection, I noticed there was no visa in it and no refusal letter, either.

Please, has anyone experienced this situation? Could it be a mistake?

***The email from TLScontact:***

Your travel document (and supporting documents, if applicable) are now ready for collection at the TLScontact Visa Application Centre, Accra. Please carefully read the below instructions to retrieve your documents.

**Collection in person**

Please come with all of the following:

- Your Original TLScontact Application Checklist
- Your Original Photographic ID
- Copy of Your Photographic ID
- Copy of birth certificate (if collecting for your minor child)

**Collecting using a representative**

Your Representative should provide all of the following:

- Your Original TLScontact Application Checklist
- Copy of Your Photographic ID
- Representative’s Original Photographic ID
- Copy of Representative’s Photographic ID
- Signed Letter of Authorisation from You (clearly stating the Representative’s details)
- Copy of birth certificate (if collecting)

Comment: What is a "collection mail" ? If this a physical or email document, please obscure your personal information and add the text to your question using the "edit" button.

Comment: Did you apply direct or through a 3rd party? What did TLS say when you contacted them?

Answer (score 2):

The "collection mail" clearly states that your travel document and supporting documents (if any) are ready to be picked up at the TLScontact Application Center in Accra.

You can pick them up, or you can send another person to do so; the letter describes what documents must be shown by the person making the pickup.

The letter does not state if your application was successful or if it was denied. While this form letter does not specify the result of your application, form letters like this are often used in the visa application process to advise the applicant that the application has now been processed.

This website is not TLSContact; no one here knows whether your application was successful or not. You will find out when your travel document (and other documents, if any) are physically handed to you or to your representative at the contact center in Accra.

Comment: I have received my documents but with no refusal letter or refusal mail that’s why I mean and I don’t know why it’s so

Comment: Was your "travel document" (a passport or Refugee travel doc) also returned to you?

Comment: Yes the passport was returned

Comment: Yes my passport was returned without a refusal letter or mail

Comment: It's also possible that the application was not refused and the vignette applied by mistake. OP needs to get more information before being able to draw a conclusion, but unfortunately getting information from the home office is like getting blood from a stone.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica The Home Office is legally required, by the Immigration Rules, to issue a refusal notice. It is mandatory. However, in some cases, they are not sent by mistake. It would still exist though.

Comment: @MJeffryes Thank you for the correction. So does the OP go back to TLSContact, or try to contact the Home Office directly?

Comment: That's one line of attack. I would also suggest OP immediately makes a 'specific' personal information request to the Home Office for the decision letter. While turnaround is about a month, it is probably the most reliable method, and it is free. https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/requests-for-personal-data-uk-visas-and-immigration/request-personal-information-held-by-uk-visas-and-immigration

Comment: @MJeffryes That's useful information. I think it should be presented here as an Answer, as Comments don't necessarily persist.

Comment: @Gynna Did you look at every page of your passport? Does your passport contain a new vignette (a physical sticker) or a new UK visa stamp?

Comment: I have looked through every page and there’s no stamp I called them today and they said the have escalated the case to the right department they would reply within 15 working days